# How to send multiple files through SFTP from KSH Unix script

Tags: unix, ksh

How do I transfer multiple files through SFTP using KSH unix script.

I am having the following information regarding the legacy system.

```
echo "Current Directory : " $l_out_path 
echo "Data File(s)      : " $l_data_file
echo "Destination Path  : " $l_ftp_path
echo "FTP USER      : " $ftpuser
```

All help in this regards are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this *might* be what you're looking for:

```
echo "put $l_out_path/$l_data_file" | sftp -b - -oUser="$ftpuser" "$l_ftp_path"
```

What exactly are you having difficulty with? What do the contents of those variables look like? Their names and descriptions provide some information, but perhaps not enough.